# Subsetting nested list in r: select first 3 elements from each and bind as df with cols to differentiate them

Tags: r, list, subset

1. In a nested list (list of lists), select the first three elements from each list (alternative: select by name (eg: c("hm", "ht", "cpht"))
2. combine each list into a df with cols to differentiate them (see end result)

---

Example data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  gene = c("a", "b", "c"),
  mutation = c("x", "y", "z"))

list1 <- list(
  hm = df1,
  ht = df1,
  cpht = df1,
  panel = df1)

list_o_lists <- list(
  pt1 = list1,
  pt2 = list1,
  pt3 = list1)
```

---

Expected result 1:

```
list_desired <- list(
  hm = df1,
  ht = df1,
  cpht = df1)

list_o_lists_desired <- list(
  pt1 = list_desired,
  pt2 = list_desired,
  pt3 = list_desired)
```

---

Solution for 2:
(NB: found the solution while typing the example data)

```
lol_final <- map(list_o_lists_desired, bind_rows, .id = "type")
df_final <- bind_rows(lol_final, .id = "pt")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 1:

```r
lapply(list_o_lists, `[`, 1:3)
##> $pt1
##> $pt1$hm
##>   gene mutation
##> 1    a        x
##> 2    b        y
##> 3    c        z
##> 
##> $pt1$ht
##>   gene mutation
##> 1    a        x
##> 2    b        y
##> 3    c        z
##> 
##> $pt1$cpht
##>   gene mutation
##> 1    a        x
##> 2    b        y
##> 3    c        z
##> 
##> 
##> $pt2
##> $pt2$hm
##>   gene mutation
##> 1    a        x
##> 2    b        y
##> 3    c        z
##> 
##> $pt2$ht
##>   gene mutation
##> 1    a        x
##> 2    b        y
##> 3    c        z
##> 
##> $pt2$cpht
##>   gene mutation
##> 1    a        x
##> 2    b        y
##> 3    c        z
##> 
##> 
##> $pt3
##> $pt3$hm
##>   gene mutation
##> 1    a        x
##> 2    b        y
##> 3    c        z
##> 
##> $pt3$ht
##>   gene mutation
##> 1    a        x
##> 2    b        y
##> 3    c        z
##> 
##> $pt3$cpht
##>   gene mutation
##> 1    a        x
##> 2    b        y
##> 3    c        z
```

Answer (score 0):

alternative: selection by name:

```
lapply(list_o_lists, `[`, c("hm", "ht", "cpht")
```

Thanks a lot Stefano! (guess my R got a bit rusty during a clinical year in the ICU)